# Moving entities above a tile entity

Tags: java, minecraft-modding, modding

Sorry if my code looks amateur I just started modding, although I have experience in Java.

I have a tile entity checking every frame if there are entities above it. It works, but then stops after 1 tick. Here is the code I am using.

```
import java.util.List;

import net.minecraft.entity.Entity;
import net.minecraft.tileentity.TileEntity;
import net.minecraft.util.ITickable;
import net.minecraft.util.math.AxisAlignedBB;

public class TileEntityConveyor extends TileEntity implements ITickable {

    public static float speed = 1f;

    @Override
    public void update() {
        if (this.worldObj.isRemote)
            return;
        double x = this.pos.getX();
        double y = this.pos.getY();
        double z = this.pos.getZ();

        AxisAlignedBB collsion = new AxisAlignedBB(x, y, z, x + 1, y + 2, z + 1);

        List<Entity> list = this.worldObj.getEntitiesWithinAABB(Entity.class, collsion);

        for (Entity entity : list) {
            entity.motionX += speed;
            //          this.
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You should analyze what part of the method fails, e.g., is `this.worldObj.isRemote` true after one tick, is the returned `list` empty, is `speed == 0` after the first tick, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually FOUR sides in minecraft, but they are usually just shortened to two. There's a ***physical server***, which is the server in the real world, the ***physical client***, which is the client in the real world, the ***logical server***, the server that you know as the server in game, and the ***logical client***, the client you play.

`World#isRemote` simply checks if the method you are running is in the ***logical server*** (`false`) or the ***logical client*** (`true`).